# Why is $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty})$ a complete topological field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, local-fields

In Matthias Wulkau's exposition of Scholze's thesis, the term *perfectoid field* is defined as follows:

> Let $K$ be a field endowed with a non-archimedian absolute value $\lvert\cdot\rvert$, and let $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathfrak{m}$ be the closed and open unit balls in $K$, respectively. We say that $K$ is a *perfectoid field* if $\lvert K^\times\rvert\subset\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ is non-discrete, if $\operatorname{char}(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})=p>0$, and if the Frobenius map $$\Phi:\mathcal{O}_K/(p)\to\mathcal{O}_K/(p),\ \ x\mapsto x^p$$ is surjective.

Now, I'm slightly confused by this definition, since I know that $L:=\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty})$ is meant to be an example of a perfectoid field, however, it would seem to me (by analogy with $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$) that $L$ is not complete, and I'm having trouble seeing why $L$ should be complete.

Comment: I think that $L$ is not perfectoid, precisely because it is not complete. Its completion, however, is perfectoid,

Comment: Yeah, I agree, any time you've heard that used as an example, they either said it was the completion of that field, or they forget to mention it.

Comment: Note that since $K = \mathbf{Q}_p(p^{1/p^{\infty}})$ has henselian valuation ring (direct limit of complete discrete valuation rings), its Galois theory is canonically identified with that of its completion in the sense that $E \rightsquigarrow \widehat{K} \otimes_K E$ is an equivalence between the categories of finite etale $K$-algebras and finite etale $\widehat{K}$-algebras; see [2.3.1, 2.4.1-2.4.3] in Berkovich's paper on etale cohomology for non-archimedean spaces in Publ. Math. IHES 78. Making "algebraic approximations" to perfectoid constructions is important in some proofs.

Comment: Note that you do not ask that the field be complete in you boxed statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was alredy answered in the comments, it is the $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty})$ that is a perfectoid field.

But here is a reference for completeness

- Matthias Wulkau, [Review of perfectoid fields](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~G.QpAsPi1geom/manuscripts/PF.pdf) (2015) [Remark 1]